# Why C++ class constructor parameter isn't allowed to have same identifier as class attribute?

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, initialization, parameter-passing

I have encountered a problem regarding passing pointer to object into the constructor of another class in C++. Here is the minimal code:

**class A**

```
#include "B.h"
#include "C.h"

class A {
     
public:
    
    A();  
    void init(void);
    
private:
  
    C c;
    B b01;
    B b02;
    B* b[2];

};

A::A() : b01(&c), b02(&c) {
  b[0] = &b01; 
  b[1] = &b02;
}

void A::init(void) {
    for (B *device : b) {
        device->init();
    }
}
```

**class B**

```
#include "C.h"
#include "Listener.h"

class B : public Listener {
    
public:
    
    B(C* p_c);   
    void init(void);
    void notify(void);
    
private:
    
    C* p_c;
    
};

B::B(C* p_c) {p_c = p_c;}
    
void B::init(void) {p_c->registerListener(this);}

void B::notify(void) {}
```

**Listener interface**

```
class Listener {
    public:
        virtual void notify(void) = 0;
};
```

**class C**

```
#include <cstdint>
#include "Listener.h"

class C {   
    
public:
    
    C();
    bool registerListener(Listener *listener) ;
            
private:
    
    static constexpr uint8_t max_no_listeners = 2;
    uint8_t no_registered_listeners;
    Listener* listeners[max_no_listeners];
        
};

C::C() {
    no_registered_listeners = 0;
}
        
bool C::registerListener(Listener *listener) {
    if (no_registered_listeners < max_no_listeners) {
        listeners[no_registered_listeners] = listener;
        no_registered_listeners++;
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**main**

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    A a;
    a.init();
    
    return 0;
}
```

In case identifier of the parameter in `B` class constructor is the same as identifier of the `B` class attribute, the above mentioned code crashes due to *Segmentation fault* as soon as code execution steps into the `registerListener` method in class `C`. In case the identifier of the parameter in `B` class constructor differs from the identifier of the `B` class attribute, the program works.

Can anybody give me an advice why this occurs? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `B::B(C* p_c) {p_c = p_c;}` -> `B::B(C* p_c):p_c(p_c) {}`

Comment: Or `this->p_c = p_c;`

Comment: Thanks for suggestions how to solve that issue. Please can you tell me what is the cause of malfunction of my program? What I have really did by my mistake?

Comment: `p_c = p_c;` assigns the argument to itself. That's at most useless but not a problem itself (and probably recognized and eliminated by the optimizer). The real problem is that `this->p_c` is left uninitialized - concerning raw pointer almost always a problem (and a potential reason for Undefined Behavior - except you never use `this->p_c`).

Comment: @Scheff thank you very much for clarification.